# Trouble with fourier coefficients

Tags: physics, fourier-series

I feel like this is a really simple question and that my brain is just not working.

I am looking at [this paper](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opticsinfobase.org%2FDirectPDFAccess%2FE01826F9-D795-926D-F83905252B97DF91_58408%2Fjosa-72-7-839.pdf%3Fda%3D1%26id%3D58408%26seq%3D0%26mobile%3Dno&org=University%20of%20Rochester) and I am looking at the T matrix defined under equation 20.  The author says that $A_{m,n}=\alpha_nD_{m-n}$.  I am having trouble trying to figure out what the values of D are.  I believe that they are the same as Equation 7, but with D(x) replacing a(x).  Is this correct, or do I have to compute them on my own?

Comment: Link doesn't work.  Perhaps you can write the equations here.

Comment: Does the link work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Eq. (13), where the authors define

$$D(x) = \frac{a'(x)}{1+a'(x)^2}$$

where $a'(x) = (d/dx)a(x)$.  The coefficients $D_m$ are defined as

$$D(x) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} D_m e^{i m K x}$$

where $d=2 \pi/k$ is the period of the function $a$.

$D(x)$ is **not** the same as $a(x)$ by Eq. (13).  The coefficients $D_m$ are given by

$$D_m = \frac{1}{d} \int_0^d dx \frac{a'(x)}{1+a'(x)^2} e^{-i m K x}$$